# MySQL is too slow

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

I have a project with PHP/Laravel/MariaDB, the DB is getting bigger every day
now some tables has 4kk+ records already

Server is 4GB RAM + Ubuntu 14.04 + Apache (DigitalOcean)

when I only start the server (or reboot it), everything works smooth,
but few hours later, any request to `mysql` is extremely slow

at all the times I have 1.5-2Gb of free RAM, and I can't find any indications, what's wrong there. If I restart `mysql` process, it all get back to normal state, but it happens again few hours later.

I believe DB structure is good, indexes and everything. Because it is working pretty good first few hours.

I changed in `my.cnf`:

```
innodb_log_file_size    = 500M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
```

I tried to set up `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 3G, but mysql won't start after that

I tried to google any possible combination of the words, and try to implement different solutions, but it's not helping. I really can use an advice

Comment: I found the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9815155/846437, but there is no answer. I also have enough of free RAM (1595), swap (1023), and lots of php scripts who work with MySQL at once

Comment: Helpful: [Testing performance of queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2756100/1066234)

Answer (score 1):

Your system *probably* was "swapping".  The is extremely detrimental to MySQL performance.  And usually the quick fix is to shrink the buffer_pool.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1500M` is about all that can be safely done in a "small" 4GB machines.

Keep in mind that the buffer_pool is a "cache".  Changing the size by a small amount has only a minor impact on MySQL's performance -- unless it is too small.  You seem to have it too big, thereby leading to OS issues, out size of MySQL.

Did you change anything else in my.cnf?

Also decrease `max_connections`.  100 is usually good, but maybe 50 would be better in your case.  And decrease the number of Apache children it will create.  30 might be good.

Comment: no, only what I described in the original post. Most "advices" recommends to have buffer_pool to 50-70% of RAM, that's what I did. I changed it back now, need some time to confirm if it will help

Comment: Those recommendations assume you have more than 4GB -- you can't buy a machine that tiny any more.  (OK VMs can get even smaller.)  Furthermore you implied that you have Apache, PHP, laravel, etc also running.  So, 50% of what is left after accounting for them may be ok.

Comment: it helped, a little, but the problem is still exists. Now it is still "swapping" every day, not every few hours

Comment: @lasoweq, "it is still swapping...", what process is swapping, MySQL or something else?

Comment: @lasoweq - I added a paragraph.

Comment: we resolved the issue, we tried different settings and, to be honest, I don't know what exactly helped us then, but now I'm not working on this project anymore, so I'm sorry for wasting your time, but I'm not looking for the answer anymore

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to see what queries are slow? Do you have the slow_query_log turned on? What may seem like "good" indexes originally may simply be good because the queries.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403793/how-can-i-enable-mysqls-slow-query-log-without-restarting-mysql

Comment: yes, I tried that. There is nothing in the log. it's exactly "swapping", as @RickJames described. Sadly, but I couldn't defeat that, but partially solved it by moving some parts to Redis

Answer (score 0):

Give `innodb_buffer_pool_size` at least 70 to 80 % of installed physical memory.
Check the `innodb_log_file_size` and `innodb_sort_buffer_size`. This can help you and also clear the slow query log if it exceeds.